# Can't draw completely using Open GL ES 2.0 in cocos 2d 2.0 in a game tutorial

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently working on this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1 and trying to get the hills correctly drawn. However, the tutorial have been written before cocos 2.0 and therefore it doesnt involve shaders. So, im trying to convert it. So far, I have not succeeded and getting images like these:

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

[image]

As it can be seen, it doesn't draw the hills completely and colors of the hills are wrong too.
Also it stops drawing them completely after 2 or 3 seconds. Here is the part of the code, I draw them.

```
- (void) draw {

    [self.shaderProgram use];
    [self.shaderProgram setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix];

    ccGLBlendFunc( CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST );
    ccGLBindTexture2D(_stripes.texture.name);

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_Position);

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillTexCoords);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nHillVertices);
}
```

If needed I can share more of the code. I am hoping that anybody have had this problem before can help me or suggest a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Even though the IOS simulation is pretty good sometimes that doesn't  run with texture of opengl es 2.0 . So If you want to get the real result test in any device 3gs+

Comment: Pretty cool effect ha!

Comment: Have you tried checking for GL errors with glGetError()? It might tell you something. Are you sending correct buffers and matrices? Are buffer/array flags correct? What shader do you use?

Comment: I think they've updated the tutorial to work with shaders. Check out the site.